# What is the best shade of grey for hovering over black?

Tags: website-design, color, css, color-theory

What is the best shade of grey for hovering over black in a Middle-age-themed website. Preferably, answer with the exact 16-bit name.

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot as an example and tell us what you've tried and why you weren't satisfied with that. Without that, this question is impossible to answer in a hiatus.

Comment: _Best_ is very subjective. Best for what, legibility/contrast? Best for style? Why is your example not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule it's best to go for a contrast of 50% between different interactions/design elements to ensure they are clearly visible to the viewer. So if you're wanting a grey to contrast with #000000, go for #808080 or lighter.

I don't remember where I read the 50% rule, possibly somewhere in Google's app design guidelines. Anyway, I've been applying it to my designs for years and I've not had any problems with legibility since.